# Expected `dd-MM-yyyy` to be a date. i am using Date() to change the date data to assure it is a date datatype

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Expected `dd-MM-yyyy` to be a date. i am using Date() to change the date data to assure it is a date datatype. but still getting the same error: `Expected 31-03-2016 to be a date`.

```
$scope.wagetyperanges[i].fromDate = new Date($scope.wagetyperanges[i].fromDate);
```

help me.
if any one alive.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Date's, prepare to be amazed and annoyed. I suggest you use a libary that has done most of the iffy niffy stuff that's done in it. https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: I don't use a library myself. Anway, can you tell me the value of `$scope.wagetyperanges[i].fromDate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [momentJS](http://momentjs.com) and your life related to dates will be simple, use `toDate()` of moment to convert `moment Object` to javascript `Date Object`

```
$scope.wagetyperanges[i].fromDate = moment($scope.wagetyperanges[i].fromDate, "DD-MM-YYYY").toDate(); //31-03-2016
```